# Can't save image as eps in matplotlib when using tex since new install

Tags: eps, python, matplotlib

I want to save a plot from matplotlib as an eps file, which has worked previously with no problem. However, today I reinstalled latex and ever since, I have trouble with eps. I have the following MWE

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc

rc('text', usetex=True)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(0,0, label = r'$8$')
plt.savefig('plot.jpg')
plt.savefig('plot.eps')
plt.close()
```

that does not produce an error message. The jpg is saved correctly, but the eps file is just plain white. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling latex with

```
sudo apt-get remove dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended texmf texlive tex-common cm-super
sudo apt-get install dvipng texlive-latex-extra texlive-fonts-recommended cm-super
```

but still have the same problem. I am using Ubuntu 18.04.4, Matplotlib 3.2.1, Python 3.6.9. I tried running the script via Spyder and via command line, neither worked. Does anyone know what could be the problem?

I inserted the tex file generated in matplotlib.cache into a latex editor and it did not compile, instead gave an error `unknown graphics extension ps` for the line `\includegraphics*[angle=0]{/tmp/tmpnu3znvkl/tmp.ps}`. Could the problem be that somehow latex confuses ps and eps?

Comment: Just wondering, if you remove the latex stuff, can you obtain an eps file from the code? if not, seems it is not related to LaTeX?

Comment: I can obtain the eps when I remove the latex. So it seems to be latex related.

Comment: I don't have a solution yet, but I have found as a workaround that I can save it as a pdf and then convert it in the terminal with pdftops -eps plot.pdf plot.eps

Comment: EPS is a deprecated format superseded by PDF about twenty years ago. Use PDF straight ahead.

Comment: I just tried doing `pip3 install matplotlib` and then `python3 frei.py` (your sample file) and got the same result for the EPS and JPG files.

Answer (score 3):

I'm experiencing the same frustrating problem, but here's a workaround if you're using a unix/linux machine. At least, this worked for me on MacOS.

- Save the file as in `.ps` instead of `.eps` via `plt.savefig()`; do not use `bbox_inches="tight"` or some of the figure might get clipped later.
- Convert the `.ps` files to `.eps` via `ps2eps` on the command line.

Python part:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rc('text', usetex=True)
plt.rc('legend', frameon=False) # PS doesn't do well with transparencies

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1,2], [0,1,2], label=r'$y = mx + b$')  # Latex legend label.
ax.text(1, 0, r"$e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$")   # More Latex text.
ax.legend(loc="upper left")

plt.savefig('plot.ps')          # Postscript, not Encapsulated Postscript
```

Now in the command line,

```
$ ps2eps -g plot.ps
```

That should create a `plot.eps` file that you can open and check.
When I open it with Preview (MacOS), it converts it to a PDF that looks like this (which I then had to convert to a PNG to upload to this site).

[image: plot.eps]

Answer (score 1):

I figured there is a problem when using the latest `matplotlib`-version 3.5.1 and `plt.savefig()` as `*.eps`:

```
plt.savefig(filename.eps,format='eps')
```

then the resulting picture is just blank.

This Problem was resolved for me by using and installing `matplotlib`-version 3.3.4.

```
pip install matplotlib==3.3.4
```